# Target in a change event code doesn't give me what I want

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007, worksheet

In a Worksheet_Change event routine, the target value is not of a specific cell but that of the range address of the pivot table that cell belongs to.

The code below is intended to detect if a certain named cell was created. If it wasn't then no action is needed. But if it was, then the value of that named cell will point to one less than the column of the cell that I want to detect changed, prompting a certain action.

I expect the change to occur in the value of a Report Filter field of a pivot table, which I fully expect to be in row 4, but at a column that is 1 more than the value of the dynamically-created named cell "cLeft" I checked the existence of.

I detect the change via a change event. However, instead of giving the address of the one cell that changed, I get the range address of the full pivot table. How can I get only the address of the cell that changed?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim Pos As String
Dim rNW As Long
Dim cNW As Long
Dim rSE As Long
Dim cSE As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Pos = Range("cLeft").Address
    If Err <> 0 Then
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        Call GetCorners(Target, rNW, cNW, rSE, cSE)
        If rNW = 4 And cNW = Range("cLeft") + 1 Then
            .
            .
            <some action>
            .
            .
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Sub GetCorners(Rng As Range, rNW As Long, cNW As Long, rSE As Long, cSE As Long)
' Decode the upper left and lower right of the range into appropriate row and column values.
Dim ArR() As String
Dim ANW() As String
Dim ASE() As String
Dim RngStr As String
    RngStr = Rng.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
' See if the range is a single cell. If it is, replicate it at the end.
    If InStr(RngStr, ":") = 0 Then RngStr = RngStr & ":" & RngStr
    ArR = Split(RngStr, ":")
    ANW = Split(ArR(0), "R")
    ANW = Split(ANW(1), "C")
    ASE = Split(ArR(1), "R")
    ASE = Split(ASE(1), "C")
    rNW = Val(ANW(0))
    cNW = Val(ANW(1))
    rSE = Val(ASE(0))
    cSE = Val(ASE(1))
End Sub
```

I have a pivot table whose "Northwest" corner is *always* in row 4. Its column number can vary. In my example it is column 101. At the moment of creation of the pivot table I also create a named cell called "cLeft". In it I then record the number of the leftmost column of the pivot table, 101.

The pivot table has only one report filter for a field called "Status". The position of the filter is *always* in row 4 and column number equal to 1 + the value of cLeft. In the example, it is row 4, column 102.

I want to perform some additional action when the value of the filter changes. For that, I use the above code, but it doesn't work all that well because the value of "target" is not the address of the one cell that changes, R4C102, but the address of the whole pivot table, R4C101:R29C117, which also changes, depending on the selection.

How can I coax the address R4C102 out of the routine? I don't want to use Worksheet_SelectionChange because, although that gives me the answer I want, it *requires* me to select the cell holding the filter first, and then change the filter, a 2-step sequence I can't expect the end users to remember to do.

Comment: In essence, a pivot table isn't an independent worksheet. Instead it is a presentation of data maintained somewhere else. The logical method of changing a pivot table, therefore, is to change the data at source and refresh the pivot table to reflect the new data. Applying this logic to your problem, to detect the existence of a certain named range after the pivot was created may be too late in the sequence of events.

Comment: Thank you @Variatus.  However, I am not changing the data at all.  All I'm changing is the value of a filter, and I wish to detect programmatically when the value of that filter changes.